# IronPython windows 7 pythonpath

Tags: python, windows-7, environment, pythonpath, iron

after installation iropython on windows 7 there is a environment variable

```
PYTHONPATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\Lib
```

well known this variable on linux system, I want to expand it to folder
c:\user...\pymodules
I try it with

```
PYTHONPATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\Lib:c:\user\...\pymodules
```

and

```
PYTHONPATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\Lib;c:\user\...\pymodules
```

but on both ways I have no success.

Is there any solution for this problem

Answer (score 5):

The equivalent environment variable for IronPython is `IRONPYTHONPATH`.

Comment: What a shame the iron python docs at https://ironpython-test.readthedocs.org/en/latest/using/windows.html don't say this!